# Discord.js Cannot find module 'node:events'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, minecraft, commonjs

Im trying to make a Discord Bot as a Plugin on [BDSX](https://github.com/bdsx/bdsx) which is a Minecraft Bedrock Edition Server Software that supports node.js but when i try to run it the Plugin fails to load

This is my Code im using node.js v16.16.0 and discord.js v14.6.0

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildBans, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers] });
const config = require("./config.json");

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.login(config.token);
```

It worked when i tried running this code alone and it worked but on the server it gave this error message

```
[BDSX-Plugins] Loading @bdsx/discord-bot (1/1)
[BDSX-Plugins] Failed to load @bdsx/discord-bot
Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:7)
   at Anonymous function (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\bdsx-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:3:1)
   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:7)
   at Anonymous function (G:\Desktop\Minecraft Modding\Bedrock\_____\Server\bdsx-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\index.js:6:1)
```

Edit 1:I allready tried to update discord.js and node.js

Edit 2: when i start the server it says this

```
[test] node version: 12.0.0-pre
[test] engine version: chakracore@1.11.24.0
```

how to i update the node version on the server

Comment: So the server doesn't have node.js v16.6+, does it? Try to upgrade it

Comment: The Server runs on my pc so it allready has v16.6

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros not really

Comment: @iEnis — Then you appear to have two versions of Node installed and need to run it with the version 16.6 install of Node.js and not the version 12 prerelease that you are currently running it with.

Comment: @Quentin  how do i change that

Comment: @iEnis — I don't know where you've installed the two versions and I don't know my way around configuring file paths on Windows.

Comment: i tried a couple of things but nothing worked and on the official discord server of bdsx i still didn't get a response